# Where to get the genuine e-book on "Jataka Tales" in English?

Tags: books, early-buddhism, jataka

I have been looking for an e-book on "Jataka Tales", I got one in Marathi by Ven.Dharmanand Kosambi which I feel is good and the another one I got is in English by Todd Anderson which is totally different from the Marathi version. The stories here are different from the Marathi one.

Can somebody please tell me somethig about the Jataka tales and the place / site where I can get the genuine e-book on the same in English?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

See: The Jataka by Robert Chalmers ed. E.B. Cowell in www.sacred-texts.com. The index is found [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/index.htm#jataka).